# How can I use IF and ELSE IF in looping and display 2 statements in GAMS?

Tags: optimization, model, gams-math

I am a beginner level in this program. I try to improve this loop according to this condition. The details are as follows:

When `CUTI(k) = CUTI(k)-4` then,

1)If the result shows this `CUTI(k) value greater than 0`, then print this `CUTI(k)` value.

2)If the result shows `CUTI(k) value less than 0`, then print this `CUTI(k)` value is added 12 with showing a word  "*" after the number in display, e.g. 10*, 9*

I am not sure this loop is correct and enough to add this condition. Look forward to seeing your recoomendation. :)

```
set k /1*20/;
parameter
CUTI(k)/1 6, 2 2, 3 8, 4 5, 5 1, 6 3, 7 7, 8 8, 9 6, 10 8,11 1, 12 2, 13 4, 14 7,
        15 5, 16 2, 17 8, 18 9, 19 2, 20 10/;

loop(k,
if(CUTI(k)-4 > 0,
    CUTI(k) = CUTI(k)-4;
else 
    CUTI(k) = (CUTI(k)-4)+12 ;    
)
);  
display CUTI;
```

Comment: You should share the code you tried to solve your problem to get on point help eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic looks correct. However, instead of the `loop`/`if`/`else` you could simplify this to one assignment:

```
CUTI(k) = CUTI(k)-4+12$(CUTI(k)<=4);
```

However, modifying the display statement by adding a `*` to some elements is not possible. If you need to distinguish the cases in such a statement, you might assign the values to two different parameters and display them individually.